# My php code is not returning the right ip address?

Tags: php, ip, ip-address

I currently have a php function that is supposed to determine the ip address of each visitor on my site, however for some reason It constantly returns this ip address: 10.1.1.27 even if I use a vpn to change my ip address (to a different country for example the US, Germany, UK) it still returns that address. I was hoping someone could explain this to me, and if possible tell me if it is an issue with my code?

Function:

```
function getIP(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); 
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                  return $ip;
                }else{
                    echo $ip;
                    throw new Exception("IP address is not valid");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the server where this code is located? is it on your network?

Comment: the code is located on a server I have here at work. Yes it is on my network, but thats why I am testing it by using VPN extension which changes my ip

Comment: well the `IP` its spitting out is your local one, your still connecting to it locally and not though a VPN

Comment: hrm sounds like your right! Thanks I will try testing it on a machine that isn't connected to my works local network.

Comment: Alright it worked! Thanks so much, life saver:)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have a firewall or some other physical device that is NAT'ing the visitor's IP Address.

Have you preformed a reverse-lookup to see what that IP address is on your network?

Answer (score 0):

This may Help You..

```
<?php
    if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
        $pipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. "(via $ipaddress)" ;
    } else {
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had just the same issue. As it turns out, I was getting the proxy IP address instead of my own IP. So I ran:

```
var_dump($_SERVER) 
//you could also use print_r($_SERVER);
```

And then looked for something like this:

```
 ["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]
```

Then captured it into a var like this:

```
$ip = getenv('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
```